# Scala: Syntactic sugar for defining multiple numbered class parameters?

Tags: scala

Say that I want to represent the rows of a .csv file through a case class. The .csv has multiple columns, eg. `ID ; x1 ; x2 ; x3 ; ... ; x25`

I could explicitly list all 25 `x` values as paramters like so:

```
case class Row(id: Int, x1: Int, x2; Int ... )
```

What I'm looking for is a short way to define `x1` to `x25` as `Integer` parameters, so that I don't have to type it all out.

Does Scala have a built in way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Var Args as in `Java`:

```
case class Row(id: Int*)


println(Row(12,232,1212)) // > Row(WrappedArray(12, 232, 1212))
```